# Android Studio - no image and button color showing in both design and when I run it on my device

Tags: android-studio

there is no image and button color showing in both design and when I run it on my device.
There are no problems with my other images which was in .jpg and .png format. Those images that aren't showing are the background for my button and is also in .png. The same problem with the color of my button, it isn't showing also.

I tried transferring those background images for my button images to 'mipmap-xxxhdpi' but still no changes.

Answer (score 0):

can you explain in more details what are you trying to do,

If that helps try add the image to the drawable folder
and add this line to your button in the XML file

```
android:background="@drawable/image_name_here"
```

also the name has to be all in lowercase and with not " _ " characters

Comment: it was in the drawable folder first still no showing and tried it by transferring the image in the mipmap but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: I already resolve it. the problem is with my themes, it was in 'darkactionbar', I changed  it to 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar' and it was solve. still, thanks. Now, another problem occured, when I click the button it doesn't go to the new activity I assigned it to. :(

Comment: can you send how are you trying to assigned it to the button via the code?

Comment: @feonicainocen You could do something like "startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class));" in case you don't have that in your onClick() method of the button.